# VBA to delete rows from a Subtotal group when cells match

Tags: excel, vba, subtotal

I have an excel sheet with Subtotals I am using to reconcile an account. The subtotals are in columns F & H. When they balance, I want to delete all the rows in that subtotal group.

In this sheet, the subtotal formula includes the rows it's calculating (in this case I want to delete from rows 104-109, so can get the 104 frrom the formula `=SUBTOTAL(9,F104:F108)` so I've been trying to extract the first row and then pass it into the range of rows to be deleted.

**UPDATE: Changed the script**

Simplified it, but still getting type mismatch in the `Rows(y & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete` line.

```
Sub QuickKill()
Dim i
Dim y

For i = 1910 To 1 Step -1
    If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("H" & i).Value Then
        y = Mid(Range("F" & i).Formula, 14, CInt(Len(i)))
        Rows(y & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Any help/guidance is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

[Here's the layout of the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw6Gt.png)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It says Run-time error '5'. Invalid procedure call or argument. If I replace x with 2,3 or 4 it says type mismatch. It's definitely a problem in this line

Comment: I think that the Range.DirectPrecedents method should get the ranges referenced in the formula

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that in this case, because the range is exactly what I'm trying to extract from the formula line generated by the subtotal function in excel.

Comment: You can try something like `MsgBox Range("F" & i).DirectPrecedents.Address`

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of MID cannot be negative.  Check that you are not passing in a negative number for x.  There are multiple type conversion issues.  Start by removing "as long" from your dim statements.  I think at that point you will find that the issue is what you are passing into `Rows()` is not a valid address for a row

Comment: I confirmed. It ranges from 2-4 depending on what row the script is in.

Comment: is it type mismatch error?  I updated my answer above

Comment: It says Run-time error '5'. Invalid procedure call or argument. 
If I replace x with 2,3 or 4 it works. It's definitely a problem in this line:

Comment: The problem is the script breaks when it goes from 4 digit rowcount down to 3 and 2.

Comment: It is saying type mismatch when I hardcode a 2, 3, or 4 in place of the x

Comment: I changed it to reference the length of the row count, which simplified, but I'm still getting type mismatches. Whoops, didn't mean to break the comment box by copying the code in here. I'll edit the Question above.